# i can't connect redis with phpfpm in kubernetes

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, redis

I am trying to connect `redis` with `phpfpm` in kubernetes but I can`t, it shows the connection timeout as you shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: `tcp://redis:tcp://` looks like an invalid protocol to me

Comment: Welcome to the community. Agree with previous comment, it should be something like this `redis://username:password@host:port`

Comment: no!! i am still facing this problem @WytrzymałyWiktor

Comment: @AnkushLimbasiya What have you tried so far? Have you adjusted a connection string/url?

Comment: Thank you! It's now working well.